# Datepicker not working in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Datepicker.js

```
$(function () {
$('#voters_bdate').datepicker();
```

});

These are the files included in the layout view:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/vendor/jquery.hashchange.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I also included these files in the view:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Datepicker.js"></script>
```

but still not working.

```
<input type="text" name="voters_bdate" id="voters_bdate">
```

I got this error also "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" when I look at the console.

Comment: Where are the scripts located in the view, in relation to the `$("#voters_bdate").datepicker();` expression?

Comment: <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>

Comment: I include also these files in the Layout: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/vendor/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: In what order? Are you using sections? You're also including jQuery twice; remove the reference to 1.7.1 (and preferably remove it from the project as well). Post the Layout and view itself, preferably trimmed down to the minimum to replicate your error.

Comment: Yes, but order matters. Hence, why it would be helpful to see how your layout and/or view(s) are assembled. At a minimum, referencing the jQuery library twice will always cause errors.

Comment: I've deleted already the 1.7.1 you've mention above in my project

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yeah, it is because I included the jQuery library twice so, that's the reason why it is not working.

Comment: I think this is because of two reference of jquery file i.e.   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       be sure you are referencing only one jquery file. remove 1 file reference and try

Answer (score 1):

So, here's the default _Layout file created by the MVC4 template, with all the extra markup removed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice where the RenderBody() is in relation to, say, RenderSection("scripts")? Make a note of it, because we're coming back to that in a moment.

Here's an example of a view we might create:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Example";
}

<div>
    <p>
        As Gregor Samsa awoke one morning from uneasy dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a gigantic insect-like creature.
    </p>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

When this particular action is called, the view gets substituted (or injected, if you prefer) where the RenderBody occurs in _Layout. If the view contains a `@section`, then anything in that section gets substituted into the equivalent section in the _Layout. Given the _Layout and view above, we'd get this generated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Example - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>
                As Gregor Samsa awoke one morning from uneasy dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a gigantic insect-like creature.
            </p>
        </div>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, what happens if we don't use a section, and reference, say, jQuery Validation in the view directly?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Example";
}

<div>
    <p>
        As Gregor Samsa awoke one morning from uneasy dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a gigantic insect-like creature.
    </p>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Our rendered HTML then looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Example - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>
                As Gregor Samsa awoke one morning from uneasy dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a gigantic insect-like creature.
            </p>
        </div>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

That, unfortunately, is a problem. jQuery Validate requires jQuery, so it will fail to load and you will see errors in the JavaScript console.

This same concept applies to any libraries you may use in your project, so spend some time learning how to use sections and bundling appropriately. The Music Store tutorial is a decent place to start if you're learning ASP.NET MVC: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1