# Adding Minicolors to MVC Application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Good Day

I am unable to use minicolors to my MVC application. This may be purely a Minicolors issue or a jQuery plugin issue. Either way, I'm stuck. I've been googling around to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated

**What my setup looks like**
I’m sure I added it in my script tag 
[image]

When debugging in chrome it says that I have it referenced properly 
[image]

But I keep on getting the error: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'minicolors'

Things that I tried:
•   I tried to add minicolors to my input on a dummy HTML and it works
•   I tried to run my MVC application > Right Click > View Source > Save to Desktop > Change the script tag to another path (because since I saved it to desktop the path changed) >> It works! It just wouldn’t work on its own when I run it from MVC

Thank you!

**EDIT**: Here are my codes
_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js" ></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("../../Scripts/jquery.minicolors.js")"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/jquery.minicolors.css" type="text/css"/>

        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    </head>
    <body>
        <header> 

            <div class="content-wrapper"><img src="../../Images/HeroRed.png" style="vertical-align: middle" /> // Page</div>

        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dude').minicolors();
    });
</script>
<h2>Index</h2>
<input id="dude"/>
```

Generated HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Index - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />



        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js" ></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.minicolors.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/jquery.minicolors.css" type="text/css"/>

        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <header> 

            <div class="content-wrapper"><img src="../../Images/HeroRed.png" style="vertical-align: middle" /> // Page</div>

        </header>
        <div id="body">

            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dude').minicolors();
    });
</script>
<h2>Index</h2>
<input id="dude"/>
            </section>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you are invoking minicolors?

Comment: have u check your console whether the path is correct?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using virtual paths (i.e. "~/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")?

Comment: @SimonC : It's pretty straightforward, actually: 

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Mini Colors 
        $('#dude').minicolors();
     });

When running it on a regular HTML, it works instantly with no dramas.

Comment: @Se0ng11 : Yes, this screenshot is from Chrome > Sources: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ahvCi.png I can also open jquery.minicolors.js script on the display

Comment: @TiesonT : I tried it but with the same result. I also tried <script src="@Url.Content("../../Scripts/jquery.minicolors.js")"></script> (and heaps of variation)... It's doing what it's supposed to, which is to add in the tag, but still getting the same error

Comment: If you use Url.Content, your path should be virtual: `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.minicolors.js")"></script>`. Also, as I note [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268699/datepicker-not-working-in-mvc4), order matters; where are your "page" scripts in relation to the library references? It would be more helpful to include code with the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TiesonT. Here's the order: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JgezH.png ... I also tried ~/Scripts/etc... Same thing happens. I editted the question to add in the codes. Thank you.

Comment: @John - *NEVER* use url relative addressing in MVC applications.  Just don't do it.  Ever.  The reason is that these are based on the URL you are routing, and any given template or action method can be reached by multiple different URL's making it impossible to accurately predict how many parent directories you need.  For instance:  yoursite.com, yoursite.com/Home, and yoursite.come/Home/Index are all the same action, using ../../whatever won't work for all three urls.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'll keep that in mind and fix up my code accordingly. The issue as it turns out was caused by @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") :( it was conflicting with minicolor

Comment: @John - Modernizr should come first in your scripts, even before jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it was modernizr that was conflicting with it and when i commented it out, it worked.